# How can I get an element's innerHTML to update immediately?

Tags: javascript, buffer

I have a web page with a text box. When entering in a `.js` file name into the box and clicking the Execute button, the file given will be loading via AJAX and `eval()`'d.

Also on this page is an empty `<div>` for used as output. If the file that is loaded needs to print something to the screen, it adds it to the `div`'s `innerHTML`.

When adding text to the `innerHTML,` it usually doesn't render on the screen until the Javascript is completed, which is fine, except for the fact that, sometimes, the Javascript file performs heavy calculations which can take upwards to a minute to complete, and it would be useful to be able to see the output as it was executing.

Is there any way to "refresh" the document?

Comment: Well, if the <div> displays the results of the operation, what would you want it to display if the operation is not complete?  You could always insert a stub value in the <div> tag in your JS that shows before the Ajax call... alternatively if you're just interested in a loading icon, you could just display an animated gif that will get closed once the Ajax completes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout:

```
div.innerHTML = html;
setTimeout( function(){
   doHeavyCalculations();
}, 35);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YKEKK/

Answer (score 2):

I would try solving this using `setTimeout`.

```
function performInitialHtmlRender() {
    /// This sets the innerHtml that you want the user to see
    /// While you are performing the calculations
}

function performExpensiveCalculationsAndRender() {
    // This is the really expensive function that
    // you want to run once the browser has rendered 
    // the initial HTML
}

performInitialHtmlRender();
setTimeout(performExpensiveCalculationsAndRender(), 0);
```